# classpath question, head first servlets book

Tags: java, tomcat, classpath

I'm studying via Head First's Servlets and JSPs, and doing the assignment on the third chapter.

On page 81, there's this javac call:

```
>     %javac -classpath /Users/bert/Applications2/tomcat/common/lib/  
    servlet-api.jar:classes:. -d classes src/com/example/web/BeerSelect.java
```

I don't get what it's trying to do. The book says that everything on the path before common should be suited for my specific system, but I don't have a `common/lib` path (not that I know of). I'm working on ubuntu 9 and I have created the following directory structures for deployment and developing of the web app that the chapter talks about, neither of them has a `common/lib/` path on them. Where can I find this on my machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which edition of the book are you using? The `/common/lib` is true for until with Tomcat 5.5 (Servlet 2.4). Since Tomcat 6.x (Servlet 2.5) and on the Servlet API libraries are available in `/lib` folder.

Comment: I'm using the old version (for java 1.4) I figured something like this might be the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you trace the rest of the path, you'll see that common/lib belongs to Tomcat, the engine on which you'll deploy and run your servlet when it's compiled and packaged.

I'm assuming that you've downloaded and installed [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org).

Since you said the book called for "common/lib", that tells me that the examples are based on Tomcat 5.5.  Tomcat 6.x, the latest version, uses "lib" instead of "common/lib".

The point is that you need the servlet API JAR in order to compile successfully.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed a packaged version of tomcat, it should be:

- `/usr/share/tomcat5.5/common/lib/servlet-api.jar` for Tomcat 5.5
- `/usr/share/tomcat6/lib/servlet-api.jar` for Tomcat 6

But my recommendation would be to get a binary distribution of Tomcat from the [official website](http://tomcat.apache.org/) (get the version of the book if you want to stick to the book) and to uncompress it in your home folder (I put this kind of stuff in `~/opt`)

Comment: Yes, I did get the binary distribution. Thanks for the suggestion.